# Android.Location library on a Java server

Tags: java, android, spring, location

I have a Java Spring server and I want to send over a `Android.Location.Location` object. To my server. I know how to send objects using `Spring` and I know how to get a user's location. The only issue I am having is once the server has the object its needs to remap the `BSON` file that it receives into a Java object.

How would I get the Android.Location library so on my Server I can turn the sent location to a `Location` object?

Comment: You should convert it to your own Data Transfer Object.

Comment: You can use GSON, a binding library to read and write Java objects directly.

Comment: @SLaks I would like to use some methods in the library as well. So it would be quicker and easier for me if I could just have it imported in my server